# ffmpeg how to zoom out with no jiggle

Tags: ffmpeg

I have read that to avoid jiggling when zooming in on an image with ffmpeg a good solution is to upscale first and downscale at the end:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -r 25 -i input.jpg -filter_complex "scale=-2:10*ih,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0010,1.5)':d=125:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)',scale=-2:720" -c:v libx264 -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

but I can't find what would be the equivalent command for zooming out?

Answer (score 0):

I have created similar command with no jiggle , You can try this out

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.jpg -vf "scale=-2:2*ih,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)',scale=-2:380" -c:v libx264 -t 5 -s "800x450" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but you can create a smooth zoom-out effect by first creating a smooth zoom-*in*, then applying the [reverse](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#reverse) filter to play it backwards. Using your example as basis:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -r 25 -i input.jpg \
  -filter_complex \
    "scale=-2:10*ih, \
     zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0010,1.5)':d=125:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)', \
     scale=-2:720, \
     reverse" \
  -c:v libx264 -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```